# How to rename two columns inside a single transaction in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, locking, relational-database

Let's say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (name varchar, new_name varchar);
```

But I want to rename `name -> old_name` and `new_name -> name`. How to do this inside a single transaction? I am told there should be an explicit lock on the transaction... which kind of lock?

Thanks!

Comment: "I am told"  By whom or what?

Comment: @jjanes by an article https://medium.com/braintree-product-technology/postgresql-at-scale-database-schema-changes-without-downtime-20d3749ed680#f0d8, rename column section

Comment: A lock is taken when you do the `ALTER`, see [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html), by default that is `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`, which is described here [Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html). You don't need to create an explicit lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it.  Start a transaction, do what you want, end the transaction.

```
begin;
alter table foo rename name to old_name;                         
alter table foo rename new_name TO name;
commit;
```